# I created a column in the select; how do i use it in the where?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created a column in the select statement (`DaysSinceCheck`).

How do I use it in my `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Name,
    (DATEDIFF(D, max(lastDaTe), GETDATE())) AS DaysSinceCheck
FROM  
    event_table
WHERE
    cust = 'usa'
    AND ((DATEDIFF(D, max(lastDaTe), GETDATE()))) <= 2
GROUP BY 
    Name
```

Receiving the error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Move your `max` part of `WHERE` to `HAVING`.

Comment: Also why in god sake are you using DISTINCT NAME and GROUP BY NAME? You already aggregating by Name you don't need that distinct

Comment: You really don't need those extra parens btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You test the value of an aggregate function using a HAVING clause.

```
...
WHERE cust = 'usa'
GROUP BY Name
HAVING ((DATEDIFF(D, max(lastDaTe), GETDATE()))) <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The HAVING solution works fine... an alternate way is using a CTE to break things into two parts like this:

```
WITH NameAndDays AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Name,
           (DATEDIFF(D, max(lastDaTe), GETDATE())) AS DaysSinceCHECK
      FROM event_table
     WHERE cust = 'usa'
     GROUP BY Name
) SELECT * 
    FROM NameAndDays
   WHERE DaysSinceCHECK <= 2
```